# Get a div Container Turn Invisible

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am trying to get a Javascript to show/hide an area on a webpage

How can I change the code below to get the desired results.

```js
function yesNoCheck(marked) {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (marked) {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="employee" value="Yes" id="yes" onclick="yesNoCheck(true)" checked>
<label for="yes">Yes</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="employee" value="No" id="no" onclick="yesNoCheck(false)">
<label for="no">No</label> <br /> <br/>
<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

I expected the blue area to disappear when I click on "Yes". In actuality, nothing happens when I click on either button!

Comment: the only thing missing is the initial condition where you need to hide it if `yes` is checked. Also, you might need to consider using `onchange` instead of `onclick` for radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onchange` event instead of the `onclick` to check for value changes. Additionally, you can use `document.querySelector` to get the radio button group value rather than passing it as the parameter.

**DEMO**

```js
function onChangeYN() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (document.querySelector('input[name=employee]:checked').value == 'Yes') {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

onChangeYN(); // initial call
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="employee" value="Yes" id="yes" onchange="onChangeYN()" checked>
<label for="yes">Yes</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="employee" value="No" id="no" onchange="onChangeYN()">
<label for="no">No</label> <br /> <br/>
<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked properly  with me :)
And the button "Run Code Snippet" provided by StackOverflow below your question also works properly with your code :)

Answer (score 0):

The code is actually running well... there's nothing wrong with the code.
You can run it in the Code snippet because it is running here correctly.

These might be the possible causes:

- Javascript is blocked in your browser settings, try turning it on or try your code in different browser.
- The arrangement of your HTML codes and Javascript codes is not correct. (Though I don't see any reason since the JS is in a method, but there's still a chance)
- If it still doesn't work, well... the JS file is not linked correctly. You can try it inside of `<script>` tag.

If it still doesn't work, try changing the Javascript Code:

from:

```
function yesNoCheck(marked) {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (marked) {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

to:

```
function yesNoCheck(marked) {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var y = document.getElementById("yes");
  var z = document.getElementById("no");
  if (y.checked == true) {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } 
  else if (z.checked == true){
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```